# Function to get my app's allocated memory heap

Tags: android, ddms

Anyone knows what is Android function to get my app's allocated memory info as shown in DDMS?

It is the value highlighted by yellow:

[image: DDMS Heap info]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found correct function:

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  long heapSize = rt.totalMemory();
  long free = rt.freeMemory();
  long allocated = heapSize - free;
```

This gives exact numbers reported by DDMS.

Answer (score -1):

This is to get Allocated Memory  Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()

Comment: Not true, it returns different value than those shown by DDMS.